# Is it possible to load an image byte wise using block?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, objective-c-blocks

I have a web service that will return me image data in bytes. How is it possible to load the image view byte wise using block programming? Any small suggestions or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] this not working?

Comment: Thanks, that solved part of my doubt. How can we write that code with in the block when the data is coming as a response from a web service?

Comment: can you edit the post including code? I cannot imagine your situation correct.